# how to check an array and its sub items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very complex problem. I want to create a function that has two parameter arrays.

One is a list of permissions which has sub permissions.:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "ROLE_READ",
    "subPermissions": []
  },
  {
    "name": "ROLE_DELETE",
    "subPermissions": [
      {
        "name": "ROLE_READ",
        "subPermissions": [
          {
            "name": "ROLE_WRITE",
            "subPermissions": [
              {
                "name": "ROLE_EDIT",
                "subPermissions": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "ROLE_EDIT",
    "subPermissions": [
      {
        "name": "ROLE_READ",
        "subPermissions": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "PROJECT_MEMBER_READ",
    "subPermissions": []
  },
  {
    "name": "PROJECT_MEMBER_EDIT",
    "subPermissions": [
      {
        "name": "PROJECT_MEMBER_READ",
        "subPermissions": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

second is selected array.( an array that holds items that going to be transferred, same format as above )

In React i am transferring one data from the list of permissions to the final array,
The component that im using is react-dual-listbox. and if you want to transfer even one item this package's onchange gives you items as this: [{item1},{item2] or [{item1}]

so i'm trying to create a function that checkes given items in final array whether they are there or not. if there i want to remove existing ones and keep the newly transferred one. and also recursively it must checks its sub perms as well whether its subperms exist in final array or not.

For example: if i want to add role_read to empty final array, i can transfer freely.
but if i want to add role_edit next then it must remove role_read that ive added before because it already has within role_edit.

note: subperms can be more than 1

If you want to try on your side with codesandbox or etc. When you use duallist bux you must provide a prop called simpleValue={false} inorder to give your options.
example:

```
<DualListBox
      options={data}
      selected={finalArray}
      onChange={(selected) => {
        // setSelected(selected)
      }}
      simpleValue={false}
    />
```

Ive also converted my data as like this:

```
const data = options.map(function (rest) {
    return { ...rest, label: rest.name, value: rest.name }
  })
```

Comment: Where is the function you were trying to create? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I stuck at creating a function to check from given permissions if a permission or its subpermissions is already present in the selected array.
If the permission is already present, remove already selected one ( old one ) from the selected array.
Add the new permission to the selected array.
Recursively repeat steps for each subpermission.

My functions doesnt work so i didn't added to the question.

Comment: Please also add the function that didn't work. We'd rather be able to help you find what didn't work than having to write it from scratch.

Comment: No problem it isn't working, you should include what you have already. **Why?** Maybe your function works for 90% and we can point out whatever you missed. Or it does not work completly and we can point out what is wrong. Either way, you learn the most from including your own code.

Comment: Would tell it is complicated due to recursive JSON structures... 
I made JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js to simplify, examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279135/how-can-i-cleanly-present-well-formed-names-keys-and-values-from-json-in-javascr or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707528/logstash-flatten-nested-json-combine-fields-inside-array and have also https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Node_Iterator_IIFE.js - JNode objects are 2-way linked example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008420/how-to-obtain-a-master-structure-for-a-json-file